# How to open launched executables as new tabs of command line tool?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-tool

It might be a simple question, but so far I haven't seen whether this is possible and how to do this.
The batch of automatic tests I am running is launching a lot of command prompt windows which are clogging my screen. I am not allowed to change anything about this unnecessarily complicated test environment.

I would like to run locally some other command line tool and force all launched processes to be opened as new tabs and thus use only one window. Is this possible and how could it be done?